# Where should I place the permission check?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I want to execute a command if user has a permission.

Where do I place the `permission check` in my plugin command code?

```
public class wingsOff implements CommandExecutor {

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {

        if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("disableflight")) {
            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage("Sorry! Only players can do this.");
                return false;
            }

            Player player = (Player) sender;
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Flight mode disabled!");
            player.setAllowFlight(false);

            return true;       
        }

        return false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I guess you'd put it wherever you want to check if the sender has permission to do something...

Comment: Please don't link to your code, post **the parts that are relevant to the question** directly here.

Comment: Before creating plugins, I *strongly* recommend that you learn the basics of Java - it will make everything much easier

Answer (score 0):

You place a permission check wherever it pleases you. If your command is registered via your `plugin.yml` and you have assigned it a permission there then [`Command#testPermission(CommandSender)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/command/Command.html#testPermission(org.bukkit.command.CommandSender)) will be called prior to the command handler actually being invoked.

If your example code is short then it's worth just using StackOverflow's code tags to save time on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Like Connor said, you can basically place the check for the permission anywhere in the code.

Here is an example on how to implement a permission check:

```
if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("disableflight")) {
    if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage("Sorry! Only players can do this.");
        return false;
    }

    Player player = (Player) sender;

    if(player.hasPermission("flight.use")) {
        // execute code like normal
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Flight mode disabled!");
        player.setAllowFlight(false);
    } else {
        // notify player or whatever you'd like
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You don't have permission!");            
    }

    return true;       
}
```

Basically just check to see if the player has permission with `player.hasPermission()`, and make sure to register it in `plugin.yml`.